# Python script in Zope can't find function name in external method

Tags: python, plone, zope, dtml

I am having a problem getting a Python script in Plone to find an External Method. Given three different objects:

1. An external method called `CloneList` (Id and Function Name)
2. A DTML Document that references it successfully using this

   ```
   <dtml-var "CloneList(PAGE,ORG,STATUS,CGAP_DATA_HOME,BASE)">
   ```
3. A Python script that references the external method via this...

   ```
   return CloneList(PAGE,ORG,STATUS,CGAP_DATA_HOME,BASE)
   ```

The DTML document works fine but the Python script, for some reason throws:

```
Error Value: global name 'CloneList' is not defined
```

Why can the DTML template see CloneList just fine but the Python script can't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DTML namespace includes the current context, the Python Script namespace does not. The Python code has to use explicit methods to reference other objects outside of the script.

You can use the `context` object to reference other objects in the ZODB, like the External Method:

```
return context.CloneList(PAGE, ORG, STATUS, CGAP_DATA_HOME, BASE)
```

You can also look up the name on `container`; where `context` uses the acquisition chain to look for names, `container` only looks at the folder the script lives in, plus all parent folders.

Comment: Martijn, you have saved me SO much work. This works like a charm.